# Minimum Wall Thickness Heat Transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

We are asked to find the minimum wall thickness of a composite wall given an inside wall temperature $T_i$ and outside wall temperature $T_o$. Also we are given three types of bricks $A, B, C$ with their corresponding thermal conductivities $k_1, k_2, k_3$ and thickness $x_1, x_2, x_3$ in centimeters and maximum temperature each brick can bear $T_a, T_b, T_c$. Finally it is stated that the heat loss should not exceed $Q_m$. I tried calculating the heat transfer using the given inside and outside wall temperatures, wall thicknesses and thermal conductivities but I got something greater than $Q_m$. This means the minimum composite wall thickness is greater than the sum of the given brick thicknesses. I thought of something which involves using calculus partial derivatives (I don't know how its done) but I think it is too complicated for this problem. How can I solve this using only basic formulas of heat transfer and algebra?

Comment: Perhaps you need to consider ABBC instead of just ABC for example. Do show your working so far. Also, where do you state the maximum thickness?

Comment: But how should I know this is the minimum composite wall thickness?